# Function to calculate the sum of numbers defined in a list and in a dictionary in python / using * and **

Tags: python-3.x

Given a list and a dictionary, I want to calculate the sum of its elements. Here's how I tried to do it

```
def sum(*arg , **argv):
    S=0
    for i , j in arg, list(argv.values()):
      S+= i + j
    return S

li=[1,2]
dic={'a':1 , 'b':2}
print(sum(li,dic))
```

But I get this error :
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "dict") to list
what's the problem ?

Remarque: I'm writing this code just because I'm trying to understand the * and ** in python

Comment: Did you try using a debugger to see the details of what caused the error?

Comment: @ScottHunter I used just Sublime text

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print out the values of `arg` and `argv` in the function, you will see that the value of `arg` is `([1, 2], {'a': 1, 'b': 2})` while the value of `argv` is an empty dict `{}`, which is most likely not what you intended. Now there are multiple problems with that you are trying to do.

First, `sum` is already a builtin function in Python, so it is bad practice to redefine it. Though this is not the issue that is causing your code to error.

Second, let's take a look at the `for` loop more closely:

```py
for i , j in arg, list(argv.values()):
  S+= i + j
```

Note that `arg` is `([1, 2], {'a': 1, 'b': 2})` and `argv` is `{}`, which means `list(argv.values())` is an empty list `[]` (at least for your example function call). Instead of calling `S += i + j`, we will print out `i` and `j` to see what their values are:

```py
for i , j in arg, list(argv.values()):
  print(i)
  print(j)
```

If you run this, it will print out `[1, 2]` (which is `i`) and `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}` (which is `j`), and then end in an error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

Now we see what the problem is. In the first pass through the loop, `arg` is unpacked, which causes `i` and `j` to be assigned the values of the first and second elements of `arg` respectively. So when `S += i+j` is ran, it will run into an error when trying to compute `i+j`, because `i` is a list while `j` is a dict.

And the reason why we got the `ValueError` when we took out `S += i+j` was because on the second iteration of the loop, it attempts to unpack `list(argv.values())`, but it is an empty list, so it can't be unpacked into two values.

Third, one last reason why your code won't work is because you initialized `S` to have a value of `0`, which is an integer. Even if, miraculously, `i` and `j` were both lists, the code will still fail due to not being able to add an integer with a list:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'
```

---

With all that in mind, here are a few fixes I recommend:

First, change your function name to something else, other than `sum`, so that it doesn't conflict with the builtin `sum` function. I will change it to `arg_sum` for now.

Second, to make sure `arg` and `argv` have the intended values, you will also need to include the unpack operators in the function call itself. Instead of `arg_sum(li, dic)`, trying doing `arg_sum(*li, **dic)`. You will see that `arg` has the value `[1, 2]` and that `argv` has the value `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}`, which is most likely what you intended.

Third, `for i, j in arg, list(argv.values())` will unpack in unintended ways. With the fixes I've already mentioned above, `i` and `j` will have the values `1` and `2` respectively on the first iteration (`arg` gets unpacked into two values), and they will also be `1` and `2` respectively on the second iteration (`list(argv.values())` gets unpacked into two values). Coincidentally, this will actually give you the correct result, but this is only because `li` and `dic` have only two values; it will throw a `ValueError` for any other length.

Instead, what you want is the `zip` function, which will pair the two lists element-wise. So `i` and `j` will take on the values of the first element of the two lists in the first iteration, the second element in the second iteration, and so on.

Taking all these fixes into account, here is the final, revised code:

```
def arg_sum(*arg, **argv):
 S = 0
 for i, j in zip(arg, list(argv.values())):
  S += i+j
 return S

li = [1, 2]
dic = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
print(arg_sum(*li, **dic))
```

Comment: thank you.
but why in my code **arg** doesn't just get `[1,2]`and argv gets `{'a':1 , 'b' : 2}`

Comment: This is because `**argv` is looking for keyword arguments, but none are given in `arg_sum(li, dic)`. A keyword argument would be something like `arg_sum(li, a = 1, b = 2)`, which would then be read as `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}` by `**argv`. Instead, `li` and `dic` are both treated as positional arguments by the interpreter, which is what `*arg` looks for.